# Android emulator not launching, stuck in a loop

Tags: android, loops, emulation, infinite

I am using Android Studio on a new windows 10 laptop. I cannot get the emulator to open correctly. The loop below occurs and gets stuck infinitely.

```
>fff0 EFL=00000002 [-------] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
>VCPU shutdown request
>ES =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00009300
>CS =f000 ffff0000 0000ffff 00009b00
>SS =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00009300
>DS =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00009300
>VCPU shutdown request
```

Comment: can you post your AVD config? Or you can replace AVD with Genymotion

Comment: I am also facing the same issue with win 10 laptop

Comment: ok i think i got the issue , are you using 7th generation laptop ? if yes there is a bug on Intel side  https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=226174 . Try to use the Genymotion emulator instead. It works well with my android   studio.    https://docs.genymotion.com/Content/04_Tools/Genymotion_Plugin_for_Android_Studio/Genymotion_Plugin_for_Android_Studio.htm

Comment: @secabhi  Yes I am also using a 7th gen intel laptop
I installed Genymotion but when I start it directly from Android Studio, it is not opening my app, simply opening an empty home screen

Comment: Intel fixed the bug and the new HAMX needed can be downloaded in comment #51 by intel user on below link
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=226174

Comment: I have the same problem. Checked that issue, that version and new version 6.2.1 not works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Intel fixed the bug and the new HAMX needed can be downloaded in comment #51 by intel user on below link:
      code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=226174

1. install the HAMX from link above
2. run your emulator and it should work fine now